# Strange results when working with pointers and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm sorry for the stupid question but I'm new to C and pointers. 
I wrote a simple program that find the maximum of a set of integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int* getIntegers() {
  int a[MAX];
  int i = 0;
  while (i < MAX) {
    int n;
    printf("Insert an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a[i] = n;
    i++;
  }
  int *p = a;
  return p;
}

int findMax(int *s) {
  int max = -1000000;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    if (s[i] > max) {
      max = s[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}

int main() {
  int *p = getIntegers();
  int max = findMax(p);
  printf("Max value: %d\n", max);
  return 0;
}
```

This program seems to work, but if I change the value of `MAX` from 10 to another number it stops work, it returns another big value that I haven't passed as input. The problem seems to be when I call the function `findMax(int *array)`, because if I print the array created by the function `getIntegers()` everything seems to be OK. Can anybody help me?

Comment: who told you to return a stack allocated array from a function `return p;`, you can make the array static `static int a[MAX];` but is better you avoid it and use malloc instead.

Comment: In `getIntegers`, you are returning a pointer to a local variable that passes out of scope.

Comment: Please don't use `scanf`. Use `fgets` or `gets_s` and then `sscanf`. And check the return values.

Comment: And please do read your compiler's warning. You could have figured the problem by yourself http://ideone.com/6BQlsx

Comment: That this _ever_ works is pure luck. You're triggering undefined behavior, which means that the compiled executable can do whatever it wants, including happen to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects) relative to objects with automatic storage duration

> 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
>   associated until execution of that block ends in any way

In this function

```
int* getIntegers() {
  int a[MAX];
  // ...
  int *p = a;
  return p;
}
```

the array `a` has automatic storage duration and its lifetime is ended after exiting the function. So the pointer `p` will have invalid value and consequently the program has undefined behavior.

Take into account that there is a typo in the program. The declared function is named like `getIntegers` however within main there is used another name `getTenIntegers`.

```
int main() {
  int *p = getTenIntegers();
  //...
```

You need to dynamically allocate an array of the required size and at the end of the program to free it.

It is better when function `findMax` does not depend on magic value `MAX`. So you should pass to the function second value - the size of the array. Also name MAX can be a macro name so it is better to use another name instead of `MAX`.

In C function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Here is shown how the program can look

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE    10

int * getIntegers( size_t n ) 
{
    int *a = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( a )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            int value;
            printf( "Insert an integer: " );
            scanf( "%d", &value );
            a[i] = value;
        }
    }       

    return a;
}

size_t findMax( const int *a, size_t n ) 
{
    size_t max = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( a[max] < a[i] ) max = i;
    }

    return max;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int *p = getIntegers( SIZE );

    if ( p )
    {
        printf( "Max value: %d\n", p[ findMax( p, SIZE ) ] );
    }

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might be

```
Insert an integer: 1 
Insert an integer: 3 
Insert an integer: 9 
Insert an integer: 2 
Insert an integer: 0 
Insert an integer: 8 
Insert an integer: 7 
Insert an integer: 5 
Insert an integer: 6 
Insert an integer: 4
Max value: 9
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happened because the array a (define in getIntegers) is allocated on the stack, therefor it's mean you return address to an allocated memory on the stack.

once your function getIntegers is done the memory is free and you are point to invalid memory.